# Calculate Ramanujan's class invariant by using modular equation of degree $5$

Tags: polynomials, modular-forms, special-functions

Let $$K(k):=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\phi}}=\frac{\pi}{2}{ _2F_1\bigg(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1;k^2 \bigg)}$$

where $0<k<1$.

Let $K, K′, L$ and $L′$ denote the complete [elliptic integrals of the first
kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html) associated with the moduli $k, k′, l$ and $l′$, respectively. the complementary
modulus is defined as $k':=\sqrt{1-k^2}$.

Then a modular equation of degree $n$ is a relation
between the moduli $k$ and $l $

$$n\frac{K'}{K}=\frac{L'}{L}$$

If $\alpha=k^2$ and $\beta=l^2$, then we say $\beta$ is of degree $n$ over $\alpha$. The multiplier $m$ is
defined by $m=\frac{K}{L}$.

[Ramanujan’s class invariant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ramanujang-andG-Functions.html) $G_n$ is defined by

$$G_n:=\lbrace4\alpha(1-\alpha)\rbrace^{-1/24}$$

First I calculate $G_5=(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{1/4}$. To calculate $G_5$
 we need to use a modular equation of degree 5

> $$m=1+2^{4/3}\bigg(\frac{\beta^5(1-\beta)^5}{\alpha(1-\alpha)}\bigg)^{1/24}$$
>   $$\frac{5}{m}=1+2^{4/3}\bigg(\frac{\alpha^5(1-\alpha)^5}{\beta(1-\alpha)}\bigg)^{1/24} $$

apply the restriction $\beta=1-\alpha$ and $G_5=\lbrace4\alpha(1-\alpha)\rbrace^{-1/24}$. We find that $$G_5=\bigg(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\bigg)^{1/4}$$

I tried to calculate $G_{125}$ by using [Schläfli's modular equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchlaeflisModularForm.html) of degree $5$.

> $$\bigg(\frac{u}{v}\bigg)^3+\bigg(\frac{v}{u}\bigg)^3=2 \bigg(u^2v^2-\frac{1}{u^2v^2}\bigg)$$

where $u=G_{125}$ and $v=G_{5}$. this problem reduce to find the real solution of following sextic equation

$$G^6-2\varphi^5G^5+2\varphi G+\varphi^6=0$$
where $\varphi=\phi^{1/4}=\bigg(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\bigg)^{1/4}$ and $G=G_{125}$

> How to solve this equation in radicals? Or, does there exists easy way to calculate $G_{125}$ by using modular equations?

**P.S.** I use *Mathematica*, but there is no solution in terms of radicals.

Comment: I made some edits. Pls follow convention as $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$ is usually reserved for the golden ratio, not fractional powers of it.

Answer (score 8):

First, the Ramanujan $G_n$ and $g_n$ functions can be computed efficiently in *Mathematica* using the *Dedekind eta function*. Let $\tau=\sqrt{-n}$, then,
$$G_n=\frac{2^{-1/4}\,\eta^2(\tau)}{\eta\big(\tfrac{\tau}{2}\big)\,\eta(2\tau)}\quad \text{odd}\; n$$
$$g_n=\frac{2^{-1/4}\,\eta\big(\tfrac{\tau}{2}\big)}{\eta(\tau)}\quad \text{even}\; n$$
Regarding your question of how to solve for $G_{125}$ in radicals, we can reduce the problem slightly by solving a *quintic* instead of a sextic. Define,
$$x = \frac{G_5}{G_{125}} + \frac{G_{125}}{G_{5}}$$
and we find it is the real root of,
$$x^5-10x^3-10x^2+5x-2=0$$
Since we know $G_5$, all we have to do is solve this. So given the ***golden ratio*** $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt5}2$, then,
$$G_{125}= \frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}\,\phi^{1/4}=3.633572\dots$$
$$x =\frac1{5^{1/4}} \big(\phi\,f_1+\phi^{-1}f_2\big)$$
and where,
$$f_1=\sqrt[5]{5^{3/4}+\phi^{-5/2}}+\sqrt[5]{5^{3/4}-\phi^{-5/2}}$$
$$f_2=\sqrt[5]{5^{3/4}+\phi^{5/2}}+\sqrt[5]{5^{3/4}-\phi^{5/2}}$$

---

$\color{green}{Added:}$

There is also an iterative method derived by G. Manco in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092323/ramanujans-class-invariant-g-625) using $G_{n/25},\, G_n,\, G_{25n}$,

> $$1+2\frac{G_{25n}}{(G_{n})^5}=\frac 1 5\Big(1+2\frac{G_{n/25}} {(G_{n})^5}\Big)\big(1+\sqrt[5]{u_1}+\sqrt[5]{u_2} \big)^2\tag1$$

where the $u_1$ are the two roots of,
$$u^2 -\alpha(\alpha^2 - 2\alpha + 8)u + \alpha^5 = 0,\quad \text{with}\;\alpha=2\frac{G_{n}} {(G_{n/25})^5}$$

Since $G_1 = 1,\; G_{1/5}=G_5 = \phi^{1/4},\; G_{25} = \phi$, then $(1)$ is an iterative method to express in radicals ***all*** $G_{5^m}$ in terms of the golden ratio $\phi$.

**P.S.** The similar $G_{n/9},\, G_n,\, G_{9n}$ appears in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310026/on-ramanujans-question-359).

Comment: I know how to use Mathematica, it works well for $G(5)$, $G(25)$,$G(625)$ but there is no answer (in RADICALS) for the $G(125)$ [see here](https://imgur.com/a/02RG5)

Comment: @vito-ვიტო: Because $G(125)$ involves a quintic root, and _Mathematica_ has difficulty with that case.